# Getting error when calling async await in jest-fetch-mock

Tags: react-native, jestjs, graphql, expo, jest-fetch-mock

Im using react-nativ with expo, jest-fetch-mock and graphql. When calling the api Im getting error

```
 × return user feed query (69ms)

  ● testing api › return user feed query

    Unexpected end of JSON input

      at new ApolloError (node_modules/@apollo/client/errors/index.js:29:28)
      at node_modules/@apollo/client/core/QueryManager.js:611:19
      at both (node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/observables/asyncMap.js:16:53)
      at node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/observables/asyncMap.js:9:72
      at tryCallTwo (node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
      at doResolve (node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:200:13)
```

**api.test.js**
import fetch from 'jest-fetch-mock';

```
import { getUserFeed } from '../feed'

describe('testing api', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        fetch.resetMocks()
    })

    it('return user feed query', async () => {
        
        //assert on the response
        await getUserFeed(20).then(async (res) => {
            console.log('watcher ' + res)
        });

        //assert on the times called and arguments given to fetch
        console.log('watch ' + fetch.mock.calls.length)
        expect(fetch.mock.calls.length).toEqual(20)
    })
})
```